How to debug web service calls in Business Central?
According to the Microsoft Documentation...
I'm trying to debug my API:

The page code is just here, a copy of the standard customers api
I've only modified the OnAfterGetRecord() trigger with this code:
trigger OnAfterGetRecord()
begin
    SetCalculatedFields();

    if newNumber <> '' then
        Rec."No." := newNumber;
end;

Also added few fields:
field(PartnerType; Rec."Partner Type")
{
    Caption = 'Partner Type';

    trigger OnValidate()
    begin
        RegisterFieldSet(Rec.FieldNo("Partner Type"));
    end;
}
field(CombineShipments; Rec."Combine Shipments")
{
    Caption = 'Combine Shipments';

    trigger OnValidate()
    begin
        RegisterFieldSet(Rec.FieldNo("Combine Shipments"));
    end;
}
field(newNumber; newNumber)
{
    Caption = 'New No. (custom field)';
}

This is my launch.json:
{
    "name": "Attach: Web Services",
    "type": "al",
    "request": "attach",
    "environmentType": "Sandbox",
    "environmentName": "sandbox",
    "breakOnError": "All",
    "breakOnRecordWrite": "None",
    "enableSqlInformationDebugger": true,
    "enableLongRunningSqlStatements": true,
    "longRunningSqlStatementsThreshold": 500,
    "numberOfSqlStatements": 10,
    "breakOnNext": "WebServiceClient"
}

I POST with Postman and debugger doesn't break:

So, I can't debug my error... How can I debug and step into my breakpoints?

Everything looks fine. I had this weird behavior when debugger was only triggered when you call ws twice. First time debugger not triggered, then you reconnect and only then debugger is triggered by ws call.
